# CSS + Bootstrap: How to dynamically stretch subdiv width to fit container (with image)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem where I have a dynamic part of my page where I might have 1,2,3 or 4 subdivs (look below at the pink arrows). As you can see in the first facebook section, the divs don't stretch out. I want it to be in thirds. If there are only 2, then it should be in halves, and take up the whole width of the container.

How would I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="channel-box">
  <div class="facebook-engagements">
    <img src='blah.img' title="Facebook" />
    <span class="small-stats-font">123</span>
  </div>
  <div class="channel-breakdown clearfix row-fluid">
    <div class="channel-units">
      <img src='blah.img' title="Post" />
      <span class="smaller-stats-font">123</span>
    </div>
    <div class="channel-units">
      <img src='blah.img' title="Like" />
      <span class="smaller-stats-font">123</span>
    </div>
    <div class="channel-units">
      <img src='blah.img' title="Share" />
      <span class="smaller-stats-font">
        123
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
      .channel-breakdown {
        border-top: 1px solid gray;

        .channel-units {
          border-right: 1px solid gray;
          display: inline-block;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 10px;
          width: 23%;
        }
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS flexbox to the rescue! Flex is awesome and [supported by modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

- [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)
- [CSS-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.channel-breakdown {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;

  .channel-units {
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    margin-right: 10px;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10);
    
    document.querySelector(".flex").appendChild(div);
  } else if (/\bflex\b/.test(e.target.parentNode.className)) {
    e.target.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.flex div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button>Click to add another div</button>
<p>Click on a box to remove it</p>

<div class="flex">
  <div>12</div>
  <div>34</div>
  <div>56</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

CSS tables are the answer here I feel.

```css
   .channel-breakdown {
     border-top: 1px solid gray;
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
     width: 100%;
   }
   .channel-units {
     border-right: 1px solid gray;
     display: table-cell;
   }
```

Comment: Please don't use tables for layout. It makes the internet sad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: Unless you need to support IE9 and below, [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is the "best practice" here.

Comment: @redbmk It's not actual `tables` it's divs **acting** as tables....and in any case this would be appropriate for a table since it's clearly tabular data.

Comment: @DaveLunny Flexbox isn't supported by IE9 and below either so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @Paulie_D, he said "unless" you need to support those, implying they aren't supported. I suppose you could argue that it belongs in a table, but if it is tabular data it should probably be a table instead of a set of divs.

Comment: @redbmk thanks for helping explain & for making the internet happier